# I want to restricted multiple logins in a php application

Tags: tabs, user-controls, restrict

I want users to login on a site from only one tab in their browser (I want to prevent login in other browsers at the time).

If the user already login in one browser and he wants or try to login in other browser then a message should show that "you are already logged in".
When the user logged out then user are able to logged in.
Can it possible without using Ajax or JS ??